# docx4j convert docx in wrong html format

Tags: java, html, docx, docx4j

I have some problems with docx4j samples. I need to convert a file from docx in html format and back. I'm try to compile ConvertInXHTMLDocument.java sample. Html file it creates fine, but when trying to convert it back into docx, throws an exception that is missing close tags (META, img etc). Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code and the exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

XHTMLImporter requires its input to be well-formed XML.  So you need to ensure you don't have missing close tags (META, img etc); if you do, run JTidy or similar first.

docx4j's (X)HTML output can either be HTML or XML.  From 3.0, the property Convert.Out.HTML.OutputMethodXML will control which.